# Dynamically constructed wizard in Asp MVC 3, based on rules

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamic, wizard

I have an application in which the user select a type of registration. Depending on the type of registration chosen different type of wizards applies. 
Eg:

- user chooses r1 type:

  - page 1 will contain module1, module2,
    module7 in this order.
  - page 2 will contain module5, module 9 in this order.

---

- user chooses r2 type:

  - page 1 will contain module7, module9, module5 in this order.
  - page 2 will contain module4, module2 in this order.

The number of pages differers from the type of registration.

Each module has validations properties. I see it as a partial view.

I would like to ask you a how should I design my application using MVC paradigm.

Thank you very much